# SwisTrack - usb camera black input

Tags: c++, opencv, usb

I'm trying to use SwisTrack software.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SwisTrack

I've installed using windows installer in 2 computers.
in both computers I have the same problem.
also tried with different usb cameras.

when I choose Input from usb camera - the camera detected, and the light on the camera turned on (so the software can see the camera and connect to it) - but the frames I got is totally black.

is anyone can help? is there someone here familiar with SwisTrack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Just image outputs flipped.

Did you select source for output window? (see click on yellow caption on window header) :

[image]

Comment: of course I chose this option - got black window.  I am using Windows7 64bit - installed the software using the Windows installer file.
am I missing something ? by the way which OS your'e using 32/64bit? did you installed the software using the default settings?  Thanks

Comment: OS Win7 x64, program installed using installer from SourceForge with default settings. Exe is in the c:\Program Files (x86)\SwisTrack\SwisTrack\ folder.